# Multiclass NN keras error sparseCategorical

Tags: keras, multidimensional-array, neural-network, multilabel-classification

I have a numpy array of features, four features:

```
array([[ 4.34027783e+01, -6.24961333e+00,  2.71744622e+04,
         1.75683192e+00],
       [ 4.34011450e+01, -5.97251833e+00,  9.95175315e+02,
         2.91536305e+00],
       [ 4.29139867e+01, -8.01821833e+00,  1.33682360e+03,
         2.40589737e+03],
       ...,
       [ 4.28848133e+01, -8.62725000e+00,  1.56982904e+03,
         2.36951067e+03],
       [ 4.29183150e+01, -8.24824333e+00,  2.92462317e+03,
         2.89438919e+03],
       [ 4.34007467e+01, -5.96473500e+00,  1.32260525e+03,
         4.77600491e+00]])
```

The labels is a dataframe with this type of values:

```
0               -108
1               -104
2                -92
3                -86
4         2147483647
             ...    
189223           -95
189224          -101
189225          -106
189226           -94
189227          -109
Name: rssi, Length: 189228, dtype: int64
```

The model I've used is this one:

```
# build a model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_shape=(X.shape[1],), activation='relu')) # input shape is (features,)
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')) #softmax
model.summary()

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

import keras
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

# early stopping callback
# This callback will stop the training when there is no improvement in  
# the validation loss for 10 consecutive epochs.  
es = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', 
                                   mode='min',
                                   patience=10, 
                                   restore_best_weights=True) # important - otherwise you just return the last weigths...

# now we just update our model fit call
history = model.fit(X, np.array(y), callbacks=[es], #dummy_y
                    epochs=8000000, # you can set this to a big number!
                    batch_size=10,
                    shuffle=True,
                    validation_split=0.2,
                    verbose=1)
```

However, I get this error:

```
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
Received a label value of -116 which is outside the valid range of [0, 3).  Label values: -97 -106 -116 -104 -103 -113 -112 -105 -106 -103
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6644]
```

I don't know how to modify my code to fit it with the input data.

Any clue?

Comment: The error is quite clear. Did you just copy this code from somewhere? Why did you choose three output units? Why sigmoid activation but categorical cross-entropy? ...

Comment: I've tried with unique values of labels (79) and it fails. Isn't it labels categorical type? I've read sigmoid+sparse categorical fits the multiclass problem